# Laravel FileManager downloading Damaged Files

Tags: laravel

I'm programmaticaly upload files, using custom script.

When i try to download files through filemanager, all the files except `.txt` gets corrupted. The files that i'm trying to download are `.zip`.
This only happened on deployment server !

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: is this package unisharp/laravel-filemanager